# Intel's "Rapid Start Technology" vs Hybrid Sleep, is there a point on desktop?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

From reading Intel's docs it sounds like this "technology" does the same thing as regular Windows' Hibernate, but it saves less data, which supposedly on start up has to read smaller "hibernation" file which in turn bring it out standby faster.

My C: drive is a 128GB SSD. When I enabled this Rapid Start, it automatically created a separate hidden 10GB partition (I have 8GB of RAM). Yet I still have 6.5GB c:\hiberfil.page file..

Does it make sense to use Rapid Start with SSD instead of regular hibernation/hybrid sleep? 10GB of disk space is a significant amount to lose here..

EDIT:
Maybe this matters where with Laptops it's better to S4 them instead of S3 to save battery, but I'm not sure about desktops and hybrid sleep.

Comment: 10 GB on a 128 GB SSD is costly to lose due to difference in 'sleep' methods. New technology does not always have to mean better. Everything always has a catch.